# falha ao trabalhar com base_url no Codeigniter 2.2.6

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando carregar arquivos do bootstrap no Codeigniter usando base_url().
O meu arquivo autoload.php está com seguinte configuração
 `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
Na minha view eu coloquei dentro do head o seguinte código.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href='<?= base_url("css/bootstrap.css"); ?>'>
```

E no meu Controller eu coloquei o seguinte chamada:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro? viu o código fonte da página como o link é gerado?

Comment: A página está ficando como se não estivesse carregando o css.
Eu copiei as pastas css, js e font para a raiz do meu projeto e ao exibir o código fonte a url está ficando assim:  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost:8084/ci/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: `base_url() .'css/bootstrap.css'` se tantar assim tem o mesmo resultado? ci é o nome do projeto?

Comment: Isso, @rray.
CI é o nome do projeto e o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: Na pasta config, mude o arquivo config.php nesse linha para: `$config['base_url'] = '/ci/';` isso ai deve eliminar o `localhost:8084` da url.

Comment: Já monto uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode configurar a url do projeto, definindo uma valor para `$config['base_url']` essa variável fica no arquivo config.php na pasta config.

```
$config['base_url'] = '/ci/';
```