# Inserir dados no db com codeIgniter e ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Olá

estou tentando inserir dados no meu banco com ajax mas não estou conseguindo, sempre me retorna a mensagem de erro

Controller:

```
    public function insert_user_data(){
    $this->load->model('crud');
    $this->crud->insert_user_data();
}
```

Model:

```
    public function insert_user(){
    $data_insert = array(
        'nome' => $this->input->post('nome'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'telefone' => $this->input->post('telefone'),
        'idade' => $this->input->post('idade')
    );
    $this->db->insert('usuarios', $data_insert);
}
```

view e jequery:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formInsert").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('/welcome/insert_user_data')?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#formInsert").serialize(),
                    success: function(){
                        alert("foi");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("deu pau");
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>



            <form id="formInsert" >
                Nome:
                <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control"/>
                <br>
                E-mail:
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control"/>
                <br>
                Telefone:
                <input type="text" name="telefone" class="form-control" />
                <br>
                Idade:
                <input type="text" name="idade" class="form-control" />
                <br>
                <input  class="btn btn-default" type="submit" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Na tag form, adicione `method="post"` veja se funciona, por padrão o envio é por get

Comment: então sua url de envio está errada, deve estar retornando um 404, exite um controller welcome com a função insert_user_data?

Comment: Existe, o arquivo Welcome.php já vem por padrão no codeIgniter, e ali em cima postei a função insert_user_data desse controller, não sei se falta mais alguma coisa

Comment: Abra a página e apert `ctrl+U` veja o código html gerado veja como está a url

Comment: http://[::1]/CI/index.php/welcome/insert_user_data

Comment: Eu faria isso aqui para resolver o problema => [falha ao trabalhar com base_url no Codeigniter 2.2.6](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118100/91)

Comment: continua retornando o erro

Comment: a url esta assim: /CI/index.php/welcome/insert_user_data

Comment: vc trocou o `site_url` pelo `base_url('/welcome/insert_user_data')`?

Comment: sim, a diferença é que fica sem o index.php

/CI/welcome/insert_user_data

Comment: Consegui, o problema estava pq eu chamava no controller insert_user_data ele mesmo, e não o model insert_user

Comment: Pode criar uma resposta descrevendo os detalhes que resolveram o problema :)

Answer (score -1):

Consegui, o problema estava porque eu chamava no controller `insert_user_data` ele mesmo, e não o model `insert_user`

O código original do controller era:

```
public function insert_user_data(){
   $this->load->model('crud');
   $this->crud->insert_user_data();
}
```

Então alterei para:

```
public function insert_user_data(){
   $this->load->model('crud');
   $this->crud->insert_user(); //<--- linha modificada
}
```